# Is this convex bounded set closed in $\mathcal H\times \mathcal H$?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space. Let $A$ be a bounded convex subset of the Hilbert space $\mathcal H\times\mathcal H$ such that

- $B:=\{ x : (x,y)\in A \}$ is a closed convex bounded subset of $\mathcal H$
- For any $x\in B$, $C_x:=\{ y:(x,y)\in A \}$ is a closed convex bounded subset of $\mathcal H$

Can we show that $A$ is closed with no additional constraints ?

I don't really know where to start since $A$ feels like the arbitrary union of closed sets $\{(x,C_x)\}_{x\in B}$, maybe I need some kind of continuity of the mapping $x\to C_x$, but in what topology then ?

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true : take $\mathcal H = \mathbb C$ and $A = \{(0,0)\} \cup ]0,1]\times [0,1]$. Then $A$ is a bounded convex subset of $\mathcal H^2$, $B =  [0,1]$ is closed, as well as $C_0 = \{0\}$ and $C_x = [0,1]$ for $x\in ]0,1]$. However, $A$ is not closed.