# Closedness of a subset of $\mathcal H\times \mathcal H$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

This is a question that I had after receiving a response to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4199928/is-this-convex-bounded-set-closed-in-mathcal-h-times-mathcal-h) question, I wanted to change the original one instead of asking a new one but it would have made the good answer there a worse one and so I decided to ask a separate question (and it is a separate question in the end). If that is a problem I can always do that.

Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space. Let $A$ be a convex bounded and closed subset of $\mathcal H$. Let $B$ be a convex bounded set of linear operators going from $\mathcal H$ to $\mathcal H$. Finally let $C=\{ (x,Tx)\in\mathcal H\times\mathcal H:x\in A,T\in B \}$. This set is bounded and convex, my question is :

> Is $C$ a closed subset of the Hilbert space $\mathcal H \otimes\mathcal H$.

I am not even sure this can be answered unless we say that $B$ is closed in some topology, so I am also interested in the answer in case $B$ is strongly closed, or if $B$ is weakly closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof if $B$ is closed in the WOT: Suppose $(x_n, T_n x_n) \in C$ converges towards $(x,y)$. The sequence $(T_n)$ is bounded, hence  $T_n \to T$ in WOT along a subsequence (not relabeled). This implies $T \in B$ and $T_n x_n \to T x$. Hence, $(x, T x) \in C$.

Since $B$ is convex, it is closed in the WOT iff it is closed in the SOT.

Comment: Is there any chance this could work if we don't have the Hilbert space property ? I don't think your proof rely in any way on the Hilbert space property, in particular it is still true that if $B$ is convex and WOT closed then it is SOT closed right ?

Comment: I think it should also work in reflexive Banach spaces.

Comment: Why is it true that $T_n x_n\to T x$, I have seen something like if $T_n\to T$ weakly and $x_n\to x$ strongly then $T_n x_n\to T x$  weakly but I'm not sure of it.

Comment: Yes, at first, we only get weak convergence, but we already know that $T_n x_n$ converges strongly (towards $y$).

Comment: Would you have any good reference on WOT ? In particular this result that says that $T_n\to T$ in WOT and $x_n\to x$ strongly implies that $T_n x_n\to T x$ weakly ? I can't seem to prove it myself.

Comment: No, I do not have any reference at hand. You can just use $T_n x_n - T x = (T_n - T)h + T_n(h_n - h)$.